# update-manager causes seg fault (Ubuntu 14.10)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.10

```
root@dragon:/var/lib/apt/lists# update-manager -d
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have tried all of the following:

Removing /var/lib/apt/lists

apt-get update

apt-get clean

All are fine.

If it helps do-dist-upgrade also causes seg-fault

Answer (score 0):

Try analizing the core file with gdb, as explained in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb